# How to time how long it takes to compile Red Hat from source?

Tags: linux, redhat

I want to time how long it takes to compile the latest version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. I have downloaded the SRPMs from the Red Hat's FTP server.

How do I time how long it takes to compile all of the packages?

Comment: Having read the comments below I see no relation to the scope of serverfault. Please read our [faq].

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going to blow up my workstation for days on end by testing this, but given a directory of SRPMS I don't see why this wouldn't work:

`time (for RPM in $(ls *.srpm); do rpmbuild --rebuild $RPM; done)`

Comment: `ls *.rpm` might exceed max. length of the input. I'd suggest `time find $BASEDIR -type f -name '*.srpm' -exec rpmbuild --rebuild {} \;`

Answer (score 4):

Create a build environment and and set up a long chain of `rpmbuild --rebuild packagename.srpm` commands...

But the better* approach is to simply go to [CentOS.org](http://centos.org/modules/smartfaq/category.php?categoryid=2). Download the ISO images for the current release from a [local mirror server](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30).

*Assuming you're not modifying any packages.

Comment: Ok but I want to compile the code for testing. When I download the source code from Red Hat or Centos how I can compile it?

Comment: `rpmbuild --rebuild packagename.srpm`

Comment: This is only for one package. There are 3000+ packages. I cannot do this every time.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Shell script.

Comment: There's no reason to compile your own version of the operating system. CentOS is available in pre-compiled form. The build process involved with compiling the entire OS is involved and requires a lot of space and CPU time to accomplish. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to make a stress test on 4 CPU server

Comment: If you're looking to test CPU utilization on a machine or generate an artificial load, download the `stress` utility as detailed here: http://serverfault.com/a/209894/13325

Comment: @PeterPenzov For future reference, your question is how to generate CPU load on a system, not how to compile Red Hat from source.  You'll get to the easiest solution the quickest if you just stick to the original problem.

Comment: My point is different. I'm working on university project with Linux. I need to measure how long it will take to compile Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux"?  Compiling the kernel is a different matter than compiling all the packages in a major commercial distribution.  And, to find out how long it takes to do the latter, it's probably easier for everyone just to ask the CentOS or Scientific Linux guys.

Comment: Would you be so king to keep a focus on the question.

Comment: He is focusing on the question, specifically, trying to figure out why you'd want to do this. Don't be rude.

Comment: @PeterPenzov You're not providing us the full details. We're trying to focus on your question, but it feels like a moving target at the moment. You should edit your original question posting to provide as much detail as you can.